# python eval weirdness

Tags: python, eval

I have the following code in one of my classes along with checks when the code does not eval:

```
filterParam="self.recipientMSISDN==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[0] and   self.recipientIMSI==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[1]" 
if eval(filterParam):
   print "Evalled"
else:
   print "Not Evalled\nfilterParam\n'%s'\ntmpBPSS\n'%s'\nself.recipientMSISDN\n'%s'\nself.recipientIMSI\n'%s'" % (filterParam, tmpBPSS, self.recipientMSISDN, self.recipientIMSI)
```

I am not getting anything to 'eval'. Here are the results:

```
Not Evalled
filterParam
'self.recipientMSISDN==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[0] and    self.recipientIMSI==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[1]'
tmpBPSS
'bprm_DAILY_MO_919844000039#892000000'
self.recipientMSISDN
'919844000039'
self.recipientIMSI
'892000000'
```

So I used the outputs from the above to check the code in a python shell and as you can see the code evalled correctly:

```
>>> filterParam="recipientMSISDN==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[0] and recipientIMSI==tmpBPSS.split('_')[3].split('#')[1]"
>>> tmpBPSS='bprm_DAILY_MO_919844000039#892000000'
>>> recipientMSISDN='919844000039'
>>> recipientIMSI='892000000'
>>> if eval(filterParam):
...    print "Evalled"
... else:
...    print "Not Evalled"
...
Evalled
```

Am I off my rocker or what am I missing?

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the type of `self.recipientIMSI` or `self.recipientMSISDN` is `int`, and comparing them with strings returns False. Add this line to see if this is the case:

```
print type(self.recipientIMSI), type(self.recipientMSISDN)
```

If not, try checking what the same expression evaluates to without `eval`.

That said, Are you sure you need to use `eval`? Usually there's a way of doing things without `eval` or `exec`, which will lead to safer, more maintainable code.

Comment: brilliant. I looked at everything but missed this. Thank you v much. I was tearing what little hair I had out trying so see what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `eval` is not whether or the code was evaluated, but the actual value returned by doing so. Since you have an `and` statement in your code string, presumably one or both of the expressions evaluate to False.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even doing the eval at all?  Why not just make the comparison directly in the if statement?

It's possible there is a type mismatch.  One of those values you specify could be unicode or some other type of string-like object.  Whey you print it, you're casting it to a string and so they look equal, but they may be different types, and so evaluate to False.

Comment: I use eval because filterParam is a generated statement that is vastly different based on how the method is called

Comment: @amadain, That's what functions are for.